# Docker (Mac) no reaction after php exception

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

The php Docker container no longer reacts after PHP exception. I can correct the error or do something else, it remains the exception. I get no error in the console.

The only thing that helps, is to restart the PHP container. 
Does anyone have an idea or similar problem?

I use Docker on Mac with PhpStorm.

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    container_name: php2
    image: tamuarchi/yii2-mssql:latest
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ./:/app:delegated
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - web2
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"

  memcached:
    container_name: memcached2
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:11211:11211"
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```